# Loggers in GWT Client Side

Tags: logging, gwt

Is there a way to report log messages in a Client-side GWT applications for development purposes (in Standard GWT libraries i.e. No external libraries)?

i.e. like the [Logger](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html) that can be used to output log messages to catalina.out when developing things for say Tomcat.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look to the gwt-log project. Seems that's you're looking for.

http://code.google.com/p/gwt-log/

Comment: For some quick & dirty logging there's the built-in `GWT.log`: http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/core/client/GWT.html#log(java.lang.String, java.lang.Throwable)
It will print out the messages to Development Mode. Not as nice as gwt-log, but still useful for some quick debugging.

Answer (score 3):

Just a quick example..

Add this line in *.gwt.xml file. Its in parent package of your client side source. The top most package..

```
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.logging.Logging"/>
```

Add this in .java file, lets say in the onModuleLoad() method

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
  Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("NameOfYourLogger");
    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "this message should get logged");
```